# Error: No module named cv2

Tags: python, opencv

***I have already found few [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876079/opencv-cannot-find-module-cv2) at SO but i am unable to solve this problem using the answers there.***

I am new to python. I am having python in Ubuntu 12.04. In my `/usr/local/lib`, there are two python folders `python 2.7` and `python 3.2`. `python 2.7` contains dist-packages and site-packages while `python 3.2` contains only dist-packages.

I am trying to run a very simple opencv example with the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('image.JPG')

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/25
dst = cv2.filter2D(img,-1,kernel)

plt.subplot(121),plt.imshow(img),plt.title('Original')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122),plt.imshow(dst),plt.title('Averaging')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

**Error:** No module named cv2

Comment: check if your dist_packages/ have cv2.so file in it?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: i just checked, all of these folders are empty. What should i do now?

Comment: Then I think opencv is not installed successfully. How did you install opencv?

Comment: i installed it long before using terminal. I have been using it for quite a long time but always coded in opencv C++

Comment: for python, you need to install python version specifically. Simply installing OpenCV won't give you python interface.

Comment: i also tried to run the opencv's sample program for python `(camera.py and contours.py)`, they worked perfect.

Comment: So is it working fine now?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: what should i do now? How do i install the opencv for python alongside my currect C++ opencv ?

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: I said that those two samples are working but when i tried to run `squares.py`...it gave me error about `import cv2`

Comment: how is that possible? if one of them is working, then should others. http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html#install-opencv-python-in-fedora

Comment: oh, i just checked that i ran those two programs using terminal by `pyhton camera.py`and they worked but if i ran those programs using `SPE Stani's python editor`...they also give the error about `import cv2`

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: i think that the problem is in `SPE` which is not recognizing `cv2`...what should i do?

Comment: Then find where is your cv2.so is located. Add path to it in SPE. Or even copying cv2.so to dist_packages should work, I think.

Comment: `import cv2` `print cv2.__file__` should return path of that file. For example, I got `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so` in my system.

Comment: in my case, it is located in `/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Comment: how do i add this path to `SPE`?

Comment: Try this: `import sys` , `sys.path.append('/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')` , `import cv2`, `print cv2.__version__`

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: Thanks a lot, it worked. But can i get rid of writing it every time? I tried to put in in my `.bashrc` by writing `export PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:$PYTHONPATH` but again got the same error

Comment: you need to restart the shell.

Comment: I closed my treminal window as well as the SPE IDE and then again started SPE....but i got the same error

Comment: `import sys` , `print sys.path` in SPE. If your cv2.so directory is not in the list, try copying the cv2.so to any of the directory in that list.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: Thanks a lot...i copied it and now its working. Do i need to copy only `cv2.so` or something might also require in future?

Comment: I don't think so. While compiling the OpenCV, you have to specify whether it is dynamically linked or not. Normally, I used static linking, so that I need only cv2.so after installation, nothing else. Just try all the examples to make sure it is working.

Comment: If you are OK with this, I will add these comments as answer, and you can accept it to mark this section as solved.

Comment: i think that it will for rest also because the only problem i faced so far was related to `cv2 module` only. So, may be you can write an answer and i will accept it. If i face any other problem, i will start another thread (another problem should be written with suitable title).

Comment: @AbidRahmanK: just a side question...with the above code, my red image is displayed as blue. Seems like rgb is taken as bgr...what could be the problem?

Comment: Because, matplotlib uses RGB format while opencv uses BGR format. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15074748/1134940

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*NB : This answer is a short compilation of comments above. For more details, please refer to the comments below question.*

**Background** : OP is using `SPE Stani's python editor`. OP has installed OpenCV `/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` which is not detected by the above mentioned editor. Adding this path to PYTHONPATH doesn't solve the issue.

**Solution (any one of the below):**

1. Add this path to `sys.path` and put it in every file.

`import sys
 sys.path.append('/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')`

1. Copy `cv2.so` file to any directory in the `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this problem of not loading cv2 dll by following below steps on my Win 64 machine.

1. Download the Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages from [gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) site.
2. In my case it is opencv_python-3.2.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl downloaded it to some folder e.g. c:\py\lib
3. Install this .whl using below command

   > pip install c:\py\lib\opencv_python-3.2.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
4. Restart the kernel and error gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and I fixed it by:

1. Finding where the openCV library was stored (did this through my IDE).
2. Deleting it.
3. Using "pip install opencv-python" again on the terminal in my IDE
4. Imported as normal

Hopefully this fixes other peoples issues too!